# Twin dragon behaviour under different scaling factors

Tags: fractals

I observed a weird behaviour plotting the twin dragon for different scaling factors $\alpha$. I used this [mathematica code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86473/plotting-iterated-function-system-images) to generate them

```
    M = {{1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}};
twindragon = {
    {M, {-1, 0}}, 
    {M, {1, 0}}
   };
```

This corresponds to the IFS:

$
\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & -1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix} (\cdot)+
\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$

$
\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & -1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix} (\cdot)+
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$

For $\alpha = 1/2$ one gets a usual twin dragon:

[image]

However, for $0 < \alpha <1/2$, I get separated pieces:

[image]

Why does this happen?

**Hypothesis:** the images are disconnected and therefore the entire attractor or fractal is totally disconnected.

**Totally disconnected IFS**

> IFS $\{f_i\}$ is totally disconnected $\iff \forall i,j = 1,\ldots,N,i \neq j. \overline{f_i}(\mathcal{A}) \cap \overline{f_j}(\mathcal{A}) = \emptyset$.

**Totally disconnected fractal set** ([these notes](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jswlamb/M345PA46/F03%20chap%201-4.pdf))

> The set A is totally disconnected if the connected component of each point
>   consists of just that point

Perhaps these concepts can help to see what is exactly happening here.

Comment: what exactly is $\alpha$?  is it all of the the $0.5$ in the matrix $M$? or the two $1/2$ in the 4th line of code? or something else?

Comment: @Claude, I actually had a typo, thanks. The $\alpha$ corresponds to the value of the matrix.